# require used to access object in PHP?

Tags: php

`require` funciton in PHP is used to access a method in an object? I'm confused, because `php.net` defined it to include a file.

```
require $router->direct($uri);

 /*
    $router is an object
    direct is a method in class
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

`require` isn't executing the method. The method is returning the name of the file to include. What you wrote is equivalent to:

```
$filename = $router->direct($uri);
require $filename;
```